# Mid-line 'Jump to next line with indent' in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

You're typing a line of code and for whatever reason the caret isn't at the end of the line when you have finished typing it.

For example, in Python with IntelliJ's code completion.

I type:

`def get_id(`

and code completion automatically finishes it off to:

`def get_id(self):`

with the caret placed after the 'f' in 'self'.

Normally I'll press <kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have the caret nicely indented for the next line. But <kbd>End</kbd> is an awkward key to hit—it moves around on different keyboards, it can be a long stretch or squashed in somewhere on a laptop.

IDEA's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> line completion works well in some languages in some instances but not in others. The example above—it'll just push the `):` down to the next line.

I've scanned through all the shortcut keys in IDEA's docs and third-party sites but can't see any shortcut to do this. Similarly, with auto quote or bracket completion when you just want to get past the closing quote/bracket to continue typing—I find myself just typing the closing quote/bracket instead of reaching for <kbd>→</kbd> or  <kbd>End</kbd>.

Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?